# Перехват вызова action

Tags: action, mvc, yii, маршрутизация

У меня достаточно тривиальный (как мне кажется, вопрос). Я недавно начал осваивать Yii и сам пока что разобраться не могу. Суть в следующем:
У нас в разработке сайт с 2-мя типами страниц:

1. «Статические», вызов которых
       задаётся методами actionMethod() в
       соответствующем контроллере. Для них
       существуют view, и они отражают
       основную структуру сайта (в главном
       меню).  URL: [mysite.ru/product/](http://mysite.ru/product/)
2. Добавляемые админом через
       backend-интерфейс. Они являются
       подразделами основных разделов и
       могут присутствовать в подменю
       главного меню. URL:
       [mysite.ru/product/osago](http://mysite.ru/product/osago)

…где osago — alias типа продукта в БД.
В действительности, ни страницы osago, ни папки не существует. После извлечения данных из базы они должны размещаться в шаблоне. Задача состоит в том, чтобы при вызове контроллера productController оно не отсылало нас на стр. 404. У нас не может быть actionMethod для каждого типа продукта, т.к. они могут быть добавлены в любой момент времени. Соответственно, оно должно:

1. Проверить наличие actionMethod() в
       контроллере. Если нашло, действует
       обычным порядком, т.е., вызывает
       этот метод.
2. Если не нашло, поискать alias,
       извлечённый из URL, в БД. Если
       нашло, то получить данные и
       разместить в шаблоне для product.
3. Если не нашло ничего, отправить на
       стр. 404.

Собственно, пока не совсем понятно, как выполнить условие 2. Наверняка задача является стандартной для тех, кто хорошо знаком с Yii. 
Буду очень признателен уважаемым коллегам за ответы по существу. Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Жесть. Понимаем хоть как MVC работает?

Есть контрол product в твоем случае.

```
mysite.ru/product/osago
```

Должно быть так, но после product должен идти экшн

т.е. получается так

```
mysite.ru/product/view/name/osago
```

т.е. где то описано

```
public function actionView()
    {
    /* Что-то делаем, допустим ищем в БД нужную запись по $_GET['name']*/
    $this->render('view');
    }
```

Но не нравится запись такая большая

```
mysite.ru/product/view/name/osago
```

хочется короче

```
mysite.ru/product/osago
```

Тогда к файле настроек проекта

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName'=>false, // показывать имя скрипта!!!
            'rules'=>array(
                'product/<name:\w+>'=>'product/view', 
            ),
        ),
```

Ну и все, теперь делаешь на всем сайте урлы  **[mysite.ru/product/osago](http://mysite.ru/product/osago)** и он как бы отсылает на **[mysite.ru/product/view/name/osago](http://mysite.ru/product/view/name/osago)** вот и все.

Comment: Shrek, ты рулишь. Однако понимание MVC здесь не при чём. Тут нужно понимание работы Yii, т.к. указанный здесь urlManager, это метод именно его. Я нашёл решение немного ранее, но оно, практически, то же, что предложил ты. Респект и всё такое.

Comment: @srgg67 Нет, тут дело именно в понимании MVC/ Понимание работы любого фреймворка, будь то зенд,юи,игнайтер, они в принципе идентичны.

В контролах указываются методы, динамически их никто не создает. Соответственно тут именно упирается все в обработку нужных нам данных из адресной строки. Но тут на помощь приходят правила для обработки URL.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, вы уже изначально неправильно делаете, я с `yii` не знаком, но перехватывать `actionMethod` - неудачная затея, а еще глупее создавать отдельные action'ы для каждого подкаталога: не нашел пользователь какой-то продукт, каталог или статью в базе, значит выведете ему сообщение, что такого продукта нет.

> Задача состоит в том, чтобы при вызове контроллера `productController` оно не отсылало нас на стр. 404

Так как я далек от того, что происходит в `yii`, но в том же `Kohana` это все **до** ваших перфораций с каталогами должно настраиваться в `bootsrap`. Думаю что в `yii` должно быть что-то подобное.

Comment: ***е нашел пользователь какой-то продукт...значит выведете ему сообщение, что такого продукта нет
Оно так и будет работать.Речь идёт о случаях, когда контент в БД есть, но Yii не может найти метод, чьё имя соответствует action, извлекаемому из URL. Задача тривиальна. Концептуально решена во всех (если не ошибаюсь) CMS. По сути, это то же самое, когда юзер самостоятельно создаёт страницу со статьёй.